# $\overline{\mathrm{Im} (T^*T)} = \overline{\mathrm{Im} T^*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I need to prove that in a Hilbert space, $\overline{\mathrm{Im}(T^*T)} = \overline{\mathrm{Im}T^*}$.
I have already shown that $\ker (T^*) = (\mathrm{Im} T)^\perp$ and have so far concluded that $[\mathrm{Im}(T^*T)]^{\perp \perp} = [\mathrm{Im} T^*]^{\perp \perp}$ by proving $\ker (T^*T) =\ker (T)$.

How do I obtain the final step?

Can I just use the fact that for any subspace $A$, $A^{\perp \perp}= \overline{ \mathrm{Sp} (A)}$ but since the image is always a linear subspace, it is equal to its span?

Comment: Yes. You have $A = \operatorname{sp} A$ **iff** $A$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. For better clarity, I suggest proving the relation 
$$
\overline{\operatorname{Im} T^*} = (\ker T)^\perp 
$$
separately (it's useful on other occasions too). The proof uses the fact that the closed linear span of $A$ is $(A^\perp)^\perp $: 
$$
\overline{\operatorname{Im} T^*} =
((\operatorname{Im} T^*)^\perp)^\perp = (\ker T)^\perp  
$$